# Is artificially produced meat halal?

Tags: halal-haram, food

Is meat that has been artificially grown in a lab (made by duplicating cells) halal? What if the father cell came from a living animal? Can humans eat this kind of artificial meat?

Reference Link for extra information: [World's first lab-grown burger is eaten in London - BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-23576143)

Comment: I guess it ultimately depends upon a) what went into it in the first place; b) the process that went into making it; & c) its effect on the human body. Were all the "raw" ingredients halaal? Did the manufacturing process involve some haraam process (like fermentation, for instance)? And finally, is the end product beneficial enough to be eaten? At the very least, it shouldn't harm the body.

Comment: You inquired a professional inquiry ! maybe it could be related to the manners and matters which have been used and likewise the sort of the animals.

Comment: My personal opinion on this is to take a step back a while due to so many factors that we do not know about yet.

Answer (score 1):

> Is meat that has been artificially grown in a lab (made by duplicating
>   cells) halal?

Yes, if the materials used to produce it is halal.

> What if the father cell came from a living animal?

If the father cell is taken from a living animal, then that animal must be slaughtered in line with the Islamic guidelines of slaughtering. If the father cell is taken from a pig, then it's haram. But if the father cell is taken from a cow or a goat which was slaughtered in accordance with the Islamic guidelines of slaughtering, then it is halal.

> Can humans eat this kind of artificial meat?

If such meat is produced in a halal manner, then there is noting wrong with eating them.

Answer (score 0):

IMO it should be OK. Generally speaking this type of meat does not come from an Animal that is slaughtered (example would be meat Allah brought down to the last supper for Prophet Jesus PBUH) and since this meat did not come from an Animal that has ben killed, the requirement for Islamic Slaughter does not apply (how can you make something haram for something that is still living, not dead yet)?

As long as the process does not include anything Haram (pork, beer, non halal meat, etc..) it should be fine I think.

This is something that would benefit society as the meat will definitely get cheaper enabling poor people easy access to it.

There is a fatwa issued on this that adds two requirements for it to be OK:

- All other ingredients/components used are Halal.
- No cross-contamination with Haram products.

Fatwa: http://darulfiqh.com/are-synthetically-produced-burgers-from-stem-cells-halal/

Allah knows best.

Comment: how do you respond to the first hadith in [here](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/2934/9123)?

Comment: @azam We can never create new creatures. Cloning is not creation. Since that question doesn't play into what the OP asks, you can ask it as a new question.

Answer (score -1):

Some view point should imply that it is not desirable (borderline Haram). The meat that we eat must have been slaughtered in an Halal matter hence if we remove the whole slaughtering part you remove an important aspect of it. Since we are forbidden to eat something which was not properly slaughtered or something that died of natural death.

The other part of it would be that we are not allowed to commit any form of Shirk. Allah (swt) created the flesh, so to substitute something that Allah (swt) created for our sustenance by something that we manufactured in a lab is sort of saying i can "provide for myself" or "i can make something better than what Allah (swt) created".

We should really get a scholarly view point on the subject, but i wouldn't personally go near it since the slaughtering part needed to get the meat has been removed. And Allah knows best.

Answer (score -1):

No it is not.
Here is why. The Holy Quran simply states that meat is permissible only if the name of Allah is said the point of death and so long as the meat is NOT forbidden (Ie Swine and ect). Since lab grown meat was never technically alive from an animal at the point of death then there is no way for the name of Allah (S.W.A) to have been said. I know technically speaking you might say the original meat might have been said Allah's name but cells die out quickly in a lab.

Reference.
Surah 5: Verse 4

> They ask you, [O Muhammad], what has been made lawful for them. Say, "Lawful for you are [all] good foods and [game caught by] what you have trained of hunting animals which you train as Allah has taught you. So eat of what they catch for you, and mention the name of Allah upon it, and fear Allah ." Indeed, Allah is swift in account.

Comment: If the meat "was never technically alive", why would you think the rules of slaughter would even apply here?

Comment: If the meat was never alive, then we can't call it 'meat' (Because meat is the body part of an animal/human etc. and lab manufactured things may look like original but it shan't be called meat then) and as mentioned above, slaughtering an animal is the correct way to obtain meat.