# Is it halal to buy and drink artificial juices?

Tags: halal-haram, food

We know that the juices of fruits are halaal and fruits are good for health, but different companies make artificial juices and sale to different markets.
Is it allowed in Islam

As a Muslim, is it halaal to buy these products and use it?

Comment: What are the constituents in those artificial juices? Why do you think they're not halal? Did you search for other questions in this site like [artificial meat](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/14913/9123) etc. before asking?

Comment: I have searched but there are different answers..
Some harmful chemicals are mixed in some products.
So, these chemicals are harmful for us.

Comment: I asked you **three** questions. Please learn [how to ask](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Salam. Your nice interrogation is composed of two parts so I will give answer in two parts as well.

- **Is making allowed?**

If you sell your product to costumers saying it is pure fruit made, then surely you are skimming them and skimming is haram in Islam. If you are telling them that this is chemical based and they know the reality and buy it then it is not haram. It is to be noted here that the chemicals should be halal if they are haram chemicals then obviously this business is haram.
As it is stated here:

> Narrated Abu Hurairah:
>   The Messenger of Allah (SAW) passed a man who was selling grain. He asked him: How are you selling? He informed him. Revelation them came down to him saying: "Put your hand into it." So he put his hand into it, and felt that it was damp. The Messenger of Allah (SAW) then said: "He who deceives has nothing to do with us." (Sunan Abi Dawud 3452)

Or:

> The Prophet SAWS (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) passed by a pile of food and put his hand into it, and his fingers touched something wet. He said, “What is this, O seller of the food?” The man said, “It got rained on, O Messenger of Allaah.” He said, “Why did you not put it (the wet part) on top of the pile so that the people could see it? He who deceives does not belong to me.” According to other reports, “He who deceives us is not one of us,” or, “He is not one of us who deceives us.” (Narrated by Muslim).

The wording of the version narrated by al-Nawawi is, “he is not one of us”. So it proves that skimming is haram.

- **Is buying these products haram?**

My short answer will be no. You can buy it if there are no haram chemicals in the products. You can always check the chemicals used in ingredients list of the product. I am listing some chemicals which are haram.

> (Note that these details are taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_haraam_products))These emulsifiers are haram. The emulsifiers may also be written on products with E plus the digit code. The codes refer to a specific chemical. Generally the codes are written on the product in place of chemical names. "120,140, 141, 160[a], 161, 252,300,301,422, 430, 431, 433, 435, 436, 441,470,471(Animal Base. Vegetable base is said to be halal),472[a],472[b],472[c],472[d], 472[e], 473, 474, 475, 476,477, 478, 481, 482, 483, 491, 492,493, 494, 542, 570, 572, 631, 635,920"

And

> The following Emulsifiers – With or Without E are Suspected - Mashbooh - مَشْبُوْه E100, E110, E120, E153, E210, E213, E214, E216, E234, E256, E270, E280. E325, E326, E327, E334, E335, E336, E337.E432, E433, E434, E440, E470, E472, E495 E904.

So if the above chemicals are present in the ingredients of juice never buy it. Else, you may buy it. I wish I could help you? If you have any other question you may ask in comments.

Comment: and see in heading: part 3: drinking them, halal or not?

Comment: @qdinar Sorry but I could not understand what do you mean. If you mean that drinking them is halal or not then the heading which I have written as "Is buying these products haram?" means the same thing. If you can't buy them means you can't consume them!