# Is loading a website with images haram?

Tags: halal-haram, image, internet

I believe on the opinion that all types of photography are prohibited, but for example when you load up a website or create a Facebook account a lot of pictures load, so does this fall under the prohibition?  Or in today's world technology is needed so is this an exception?

Is there any proof you can supply me with and some opinions too?

Also is making an online account or downloading images allowed?

The Prophet Muhammad (Peace Be Upon Him) said that if you are doubtful on whether something is halal or haram, it is best to avoid it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is drawing people prohibited in Islam?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/869/is-drawing-people-prohibited-in-islam)

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: "I know all types of photography are prohibited" - please instead retype and say that i follow the opinion that all types of photography are haram. if not it's only a statement which you first have to answer before answering your question

Comment: It would help to answer this question if we knew whose opinion is being followed here.

Comment: This would also have the same ruling as [Can I use pictures on a website?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2928/17163).